# Tagging referral to avoid edit war (re specific instance of application of 'brexit')

Tags: discussion, tagging

[Does the UK know whether I am currently there or not?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83019/does-the-uk-know-whether-i-am-currently-there-or-not) asks:

*Just curious if they keep track of me entering / exiting the UK and whether that's saved somewhere? I want to apply for citizenship, and will be asked to provide information on my travels / when I was abroad, but would have thought they could probably check this themselves? Especially, since I really don't remember most travels.*

It is tagged:

[uk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) [factoids](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factoids) [eu-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu-citizens) [residency](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/residency) [brexit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit)

The Usage guide for [brexit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit) is:

> Questions that are prompted by the "Brexit" referendum held in 2016. Those who may be affected are mostly EU nationals who travel frequently to the UK. For questions about UK residence and UK nationality, please use the Expats site at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions

I removed the [brexit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit) tag on the basis that I have not seen in any version of the Q (it has been edited five times so far) any evidence that the Q was *prompted by the "Brexit" referendum held in 2016*. The [brexit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit) tag was:

added at v4 (no other changes then),
removed (by me) at v5 (when I added [eu-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu-citizens)),
added at v6 (no other changes then).

v4 and v6 were edits made by the same user, so rather than an edit war between us:

Do you think it appropriate to tag the Q as it stands with [brexit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does have a [brexit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit) context, but it's an *Expats* one: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/uk-immigration-application-evidence-proof-that-i-lived-there-eu-citizen-no

As for Travel.SE, there's no point in having the tag there as it's not relevant for temporary travels. I will now proceed to remove it.